# Task Scheduler not running repeated tasks

Tags: php, windows, taskscheduler

I have created a task to open a website every `x` minutes.
This is what I have.

```
program: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
argument: https://phpfile on my server
start in: C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\
```

It starts manually but never repeats automatically.
It shows repeat time correct but never repeats. The repeat time just keeps updating.

I basically want to run a PHP script on my website every few minutes,
please help.

Comment: basically you need a cron job to run your php script every x minutes. Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/q/18737407/4584028

Comment: @BalrajAllam I am using windows which has task scheduler as cron alternative i guess.

Comment: yes, task scheduler and cron are similar.

Comment: The problem here is that it is not repeating automatically but still updating the repeat time. What do i do to make it run automatically? @BalrajAllam

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem in Windows 10 by setting multiple triggers to my task in Task Scheduler.

After that I rebooted my computer and its working fine finally.

This is the link I refer to: https://superuser.com/questions/865067/task-scheduler-repeat-task-not-triggering.

Below is the screenshot of my task's properties in Task Scheduler.

[image: Multiple triggers set for task]

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a scheduled task and set the trigger after the present time (not in the past time as it wont start then) say 10min from present. Then dont run the task manually but wait 10min and windows will start scheduling the task say every hour or whatever you set. Basically windows scheduler needs at least one automatic trigger instead of manually Run by a user to start running the task automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it by removing spaces from the name of task and from the executed path. Task scheduler doesn't like spaces.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).